# Converting POINT sql data to python

Tags: mysql, geometry, python-3.6, mysql-python

I'm working on a school project that consists of a server (mySQL). To get information out of the tables i'm using the following code:

```
k = db.cursor()
k.execute("SELECT location FROM api_server.Measurement WHERE userid = 18")
rows = k.fetchall()

for index in rows[0]:
    print(index)
```

The output from this code is: `b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x0c\xbd\xb4\x97#Z\x14@\x81\xae"HJ\x0eJ@'`

When looking at the code via MySQL Workbench i get some binary values that look like this: [binary values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY5zL.png)
When opening the tab to see text this value pops up: POINT (5.0881077 52.1116621)
I want this value in python too. Does someone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that is just a blob data, you can use

```
SELECT CONVERT(location USING utf8) FROM api_server.Measurement WHERE userid = 18
```

if it is a point (Geometry Type) , you can use:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(location USING utf8) FROM api_server.Measurement WHERE userid = 18
```